# What does Doug mean when he says "there" to Bo Peep?

Tags: toy-story-4

In *Toy Story 4* (2019), Bo meets Doug, whose half was destroyed by the cat:

> Doug: Couldn't take it out **there**, huh?
>
> Bo: Hey, Doug. Saw your better half at the front of the store.
>
> Doug: Yeah, you mess with the cat, you get the claws..

Comment: It’s either out on the open shop floor or outside the shop itself. I think the whole exchange could be designed to show Doug knows Bo and knows she left and has returned, but it could also be an expression of empathy. This *might* be opinion-based.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is heavily contextual to the overall plot

## Potential Spoilers Ahead

Forky is being held hostage in the antiques store by Gabby, who wants Woody's voicebox to fix her own. While outside, Woody reconnects with Bo Peep (Toy Story 1-2), who has been living free after escaping the store. **Bo Peep does not want to go back.** Woody convinces her to go back with him to save Forky.

The full context of Doug's line is he is jokingly suggesting that Bo Peep had become tired of living outside and had come back to live in the store. He's saying this in an ironic way, given that the store's cat had ripped him in half, and they are all holed up in a secret club inside a pinball machine to avoid Gabby's henchmen/dolls and the aforementioned cat.

## TL;DR

"there" means outside the store